# Do all machine learning algorithm usage Word frequency as a feature?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification, svm

I use scikit learn for classification. And mainly work with NAive bayes, SVM, Neural network. There are variant in each of them.

I see for training algo create vectors. What does this vector contains?

For all algorithm does it consider word frequency as a feature? If yes then how they differ?

Answer (score 1):

For text classification you usually create a vector of [words frequency, or tf-idf](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) to be able to compute distances between two documents. You could use all kinds of method to create these weights on word.

The words (features) can be extracted by just a splitting the documents on separator but you can use more complex methods like [stemming](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1156) (keep only the root of the words).

You will find lots of example in the sklearn documentation. For instance :

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html

This [iPython Notebook](https://gist.github.com/fayeip/2b96d0dc7ed7d8edbc7a) could be a good start too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question was different. Do all machine learning algo considers tf-idf for feature selection?

Comment: You decide what kind of feature you want to use. In the sklearn link you see that all kind of classifiers are use with the same features. But you can choose to use other kind of feature : length of the document, number of vowel. You can also use all kind of vectorizer (CountVectorizer, TfIdf, Hashing...).